# How to convert these spring security xml configuration to java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm trying to convert `spring security xml` configurations to `java` configuration, does someone knows to convert these below tags:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="...." />
    <authentication-provider ref="...." />
</authentication-manager>
```

this one

```
    <oauth:provider consumer-details-service-ref="oauthConsumerDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    require10a="false" authenticate-token-url="/oauth_authenticate_token" />
```

this one

```
<oauth:token-services id="tokenServices" />
```

and this one

```
<global-method-security  pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand fully what you want, but here some code with Java configuration annotations that can help you:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserService userDetailsService;

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Autowired
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I'll search the oauth tags. You already have help me too much.